# How does one Print the return value of a function inside another function in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I have the following function that returns the half of a number if it is even.

```
let regraUm m = if ((m mod 2) = 0) then m/2 else m;;
```

and I want to print **regraUm 250** inside another function or somewhere inside the *.ml file.

example: `let _ = printf let m = regraUm 250`

Full Code:

```
open Printf
open Format
let regraUm m = if ((m mod 2) = 0) then m/2 else m;;

let _ = printf let m = regraUm 250
```

When I try to compile it using ocamlopt program.ml -o a it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in my environement and I get those output :
[image]
You're not using the printf function properly but I don't get why you don't have any compiler error, it seems like ocaml interpret your line of code as the printf function if we name it. Anyway be sure to check the doc here : https://ocaml.org/api/Printf.html
Here is what you want

```ml
let m = regraUm 250 in printf "%d" m;;
(*or just*)
printf "%d" @@ regraUm 250;;
(*which is the same as*)
printf "%d"(regraUm 250);;
```

Comment: There's no compiler error because it's treating `let a = printf` and `let m = regraUm 250` correctly as two bindings.

Answer (score 1):

If you run an auto-formatter like `ocamlformat`, you'll find that it reformats your code as:

```ml
open Printf
open Format
let regraUm m = if ((m mod 2) = 0) then m/2 else m;;

let _ = printf;;

let m = regraUm 250;;
```

Essentially you're defining `_` to be an alias for `printf` and then defining a constant `m`.

The way to do what you want is to pass `m` to `printf`, but you'll also need to a format string (see [the documentation for Printf](https://www.ocaml.org/api/Printf.html):

```ml
open Printf
open Format

let regraUm m = if ((m mod 2) = 0) then m/2 else m;;

let m = regraUm 250;;

(* note that by putting () instead of the wildcard _ here, the compiler can warn
   you if you statement returns a valid that you're unintentionally ignoring *)
let () = printf "%d" m;;
```

You could also use a `let ... in` statement, or parentheses.

This defines `m` in the scope of the current statement instead of as a global:

```ml
let () =
  let m = regraUm 250 in
  printf "%d" m;;
```

And this passes the value directly:

```ml
let () =
  printf "%d" (regraUm 250);;
```